# Updates Warning

Tags: apt, updates

I am a very new Ubuntu and Linux user and I encounter the following warnings when updating with `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cappelikan/ppa/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                           
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/ppa/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                        
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                   
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease
Fetched 109 kB in 1s (142 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

I know I should edit the sources.list, but I can not tell for sure which line, this is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 21.04 _Hirsute Hippo_ - Release amd64 (20210420)]/ hirsute main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute main restricted
# deb-src http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute universe
# deb-src http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates universe
# deb-src http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute multiverse
# deb-src http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute partner multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

This is the output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:    21.04
Codename:   hirsute
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem being inspired from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346514/multiverse-repository-update-warning-message) question. Basically, on line 43, I had `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute partner multiverse`
and all I had to do was to erase multiverse becoming `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute partner`.

The reason why I had to remove multiverse is that `http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu` is not a general-purpose repository as stated in the link provided.

Comment: I was just about to answer your question the same way. Good job! I also updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Open `Software & Updates` and check these settings... you *may* have to select a different Download from...

[image]

**Update #1:**

Edit /etc/apt/sources.list...

and change:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute partner multiverse
```

to this:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute partner
```

Comment: Just did, it did not work... any other suggestions?