# multiverse repository update warning message

Tags: updates, repository, 21.04, add-apt-repository, multiverse

for installing MS-core-fonts i just added following repository to ubuntu 21.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
```

now, everytime i run `apt update` command i get following warning message several times:

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease [101 kB]
Fetched 101 kB in 2s (65.3 kB/s)   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/i18n/Translation-fa_IR' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/i18n/Translation-fa' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

i noticed multiverse repository was active in ubuntu software even before adding that repository but there was not such an error before.

the resault `/etc/apt/sources.list` is as follows:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute restricted main multiverse

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates restricted main multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports universe restricted main multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute multiverse partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security restricted main multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security universe
```

So, what is the problem now with multiverse repository?

Comment: i just updated output of sudo apt update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RayWoodcock explained it very well:

> [T]he basic idea is that your sources.list was trying to get multiverse content from a repository that doesn't have multiverse content. The word "multiverse" was added automatically to some repositories in sources.list, and had to be removed manually from the one(s) with no multiverse material.

`http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu` is not a general purpose repository. You are getting those warnings because you are erroneously trying to treat that source as general-purpose.

Here, let's take a look:

```
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-i386/Packages'
 as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' 
 doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

See? "*Source X doesn't have 'multiverse'*". And X is `http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu`

That source should ONLY be used for the `partner` repo. Delete it's use for everything else.

Line 31 of your file currently reads:

`deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute multiverse partner`

Edit the file so that line instead reads:

`deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute partner`

See how `multiverse` has been removed from the line?

Finally, since you have changed your sources,

`sudo apt update`

Comment: Thanks, but how? how i do your recomendation?

Comment: i add /etc/apt/sources.list resault

Comment: thank you. the problem is solved. but i wonder why that command (adding multiverse repo) caused this problem? can you explain?

Comment: @aliHOZA - I think the basic idea is that your sources.list was trying to get multiverse content from a repository that doesn't have multiverse content. The word "multiverse" was added automatically to some repositories in sources.list, and had to be removed manually from the one(s) with no multiverse material.

Comment: @RayWoodcock very well said! Edited the question for clarity, shamelessly quoting you.